# Why is my html getting mal-formed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following table in a form that's embedded in a formtastic form (semantic_form_for).  Everything I ask to be generated by ruby shows up, but the table gets badly mangled (essentially, the  tags NEVER get formed.

The table headers get drawn correctly

There are 14 available_date objects that get passed, and they alternate between having a time value of 1 or 2, so this is just terribly boggling, but probably simple to fix...

```
<table class="availability_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Early</th>
        <th>Late</th>
    </tr>
    <% f.fields_for :available_dates do |ad| %>
        <% if ad.object.time == 1  #if this is an early shift, then start the new row %>
            <tr><td><%= ad.object.date.strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y') %></td>
                <td><%= ad.collection_select(:availability , LookupAvailability.all.collect, :id, :name) %></td>
        <% else #otherwise end the row with just a box%>
            <td><%= ad.collection_select(:availability , LookupAvailability.all.collect, :id, :name) %></td></tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

So like I said, the form functions properly, and the objects all get updated and displayed correctly and all that, it's just that the HTML isn't getting echo'd out properly so my table is all mangled.  Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ruby 1.8.7?

If so, try to remove the comments next to the if and else lines. On erb, the only valid syntax  for comments is <%# this is a comment %>. That is, the "#" should be at the beginning, right after the "<%", not after an instruction. On ruby 1.8.7, it crashes randomly, mangling the rendered html.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<% f.fields_for :available_dates do |ad| %>
  <tr>
    <% if ad.object.time == 1  #if this is an early shift, then start the new row %>
      <td><%= ad.object.date.strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y') %></td>
      <td><%= ad.collection_select(:availability , LookupAvailability.all.collect, :id, :name) %></td>
    <% else #otherwise end the row with just a box%>
      <td><%= ad.collection_select(:availability , LookupAvailability.all.collect, :id, :name) %></td>
      <td></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I changed `<tr>` and `</tr>` positions and added `<td></td>` to add empty table cell.

Answer (score 0):

You close your `tr` tag only in the `else` branch. Would make sense to close it after the if-else.